# Why is PHP's mt_rand not cryptographically secure?

Tags: php, cryptography

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php:

> **Caution** This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes.

Can someone please explain what this means in the context of a website? Does it mean it should not be used to generate a security token?

On a 32-bit system `PHP_INT_SIZE` is just over 2 billion. If I generate a number `mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_SIZE)` and add on a long random string of say 100 chars and use it as a security token, is it saying that it is insecure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "security token" you mean a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce), i.e. an one-use token that should be unique with near certainty then `mt_rand` is just fine.

"Does not generate cryptographically secure values" in this context means that given enough information on the state of the generator [someone can *predict* what its output will be in the future](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Disadvantages). Obviously this is a deal-breaker if you are going to use said output to encrypt sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give a website application example of someone having “enough information on the state of the generator” and using it detrimentally? I read your second link but am still unsure.

Comment: @texelate: Difficult to give a practical example because typical web apps do not hand out encrypted data to people who do not have the encryption key. But you can get some ideas from [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/cryptographic-security-of-php-mt-rand-function-using-mersenne-twister-algo).

Comment: @texelate: Random example. You store encrypted user texts (encryption method as described above) where the key has been generated with MT but only the owner keeps the key. Someone signs up and realizes (or guesses, or knows) that their key is generated with MT. They then break into your db (perhaps a simple SQL injection) and get the encrypted texts. If a piece of text is large enough and only contains ASCII characters (reasonable assumption for English) they can decrypt that text without knowing the key.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's not really random. Mersenne Twister is based on a linear recursion, so any pseudo random number sequence generated by a linear recursion is insecure, since from sufficiently long subsequence of the outputs, one can predict the further results.